# How can i code the below shape in React Native?

Tags: react-native

[Click to See the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3uUZ.png)

Note: The curved space should be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

use `react-native-svg` to get this shape

snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/juicy-tortilla

here is the example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Svg, Path } from 'react-native-svg';

const SIZE = 250;
const RADVALUE = SIZE - 40;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.traingleCorner}>
        <Svg
          width={`${SIZE}`}
          height={`${SIZE}`}
          fill="red"
          strokeWidth={1}
          viewBox={`0 0 ${SIZE} ${SIZE}`}>
          <Path
            d={`M0 0L ${SIZE} 0L${SIZE} ${SIZE}Q${RADVALUE} ${
              SIZE - RADVALUE
            } 0 0 `}
          />
        </Svg>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  traingleCorner: {
    width: SIZE,
    height: SIZE,
  },
  coloredPart: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  uncoloredPart: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: SIZE,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```